# Fiddler not seeing all cookies.

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-devtools, fiddler, scraper

When I access the URL  http://kgnzb.rvxrg.servertrust.com/login.asp using Chrome, I can  see that there are 3 cookies in the browser. Using Chrome Developer tools with Javascript disabled to view the cookies.

However when I look at the Fiddler traffic, I see only two cookies. Screenshot http://prntscr.com/27pecx.

I see the same behavior as Fiddler when I scrape the page also.

Could some one explain why Fiddler and the Scraper sees only two cookies where the browser sees 3 cookies?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fiddler shows you exactly what is sent to and from the server.

You're only showing the `Set-Cookie` responses of *one* HTTP response; those are the cookies set by *only* that response.

If you want to look at all cookies being sent to the server for a request, look at the Request Header Inspector's `Cookie` value for a subsequent request.

This web page is made up of multiple resources, each of which may include a `Set-Cookie` header. Also, when JavaScript is enabled, cookies can be added or removed by manipulating the `document.cookie` property. Such changes would only be observable on the network in a *subsequent* request.